# What's the correct number type for financial variables in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, currency, financial

I am used to programming in Java, where the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type is the best for storing financial values, since there are manners to specify rounding rules over the calculations.

In the latest swift version (2.1 at the time this post is written), which native type better supports correct calculations and rounding for financial values? Is there any equivalent to java's BigDecimal? Or anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about storing for example $1.23 in a `float` or `double`, and the potential inaccuracies you will get from floating point precision errors, that is if you actually want to stick to integer amounts of cents or pence (or whatever else). Then use an integer to store your value and use the pence/cent as your unit instead of pounds/dollars. You will then be 100% accurate when dealing in integer amounts of pence/cents, and it's easier than using a class like `NSDecimalNumber`. The display of that value is then purely a presentation issue.

If however you need to deal with fractions of a pence/cent, then `NSDecimalNumber` is probably what you want.

I recommend looking into how classes like this actually work, and how floating point numbers work too, because having an understanding of this will help you to see why precision errors arise and just what the precision limits are of a class like `NSDecimalNumber`, why it's better for storing decimal numbers, why floats are good at storing numbers like 17/262144 (i.e. where the denominator is a power of two) but can't store 1/100, etc.

Comment: I accepted this answer since it is more complete. The option of storing the cents as integers should be enough in many cases (such as just storing values). In my case, the app needs to calculate instalments, and rounds are necessary, e.g. $10 divided by 3 would be $3.333333... and one simply cannot pay fractions of cents.

Comment: In this case you should use integer modular arithmetic. For example $10 = 1000¢, (1000 / 3) using integer arithmetic gives 333¢, and (1000 % 3) gives 1, so you have a total remainder of 1¢ which you need to add to one of the installments. This gives us exactly 333 + 333 + 334 = 1000¢ - display these as dollars and you have $3.33 + $3.33 + $3.34. No loss of precision and perfect results that add up with no rounding errors. @jotaEsse

Comment: for sure @jhabbott, that should be considered also, but this was just an example. I forgot to mention, for instance, that there is interest involved, but anyways, thank you for the explanation. I am sure someone facing the issue will have it as an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSDecimal` or `NSDecimalNumber` for arbitrary precision numbers.

See more on [`NSDecimalNumbers`'s reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/).